# how to escape special characters dot and double quotes in java?

Tags: java, string, escaping

Columnname : Meta Data["1. Information"]

```
String column = columnname.replaceAll(".","\\.").replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
```

I am trying to escape both double quotes and dot character,How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `(\\\")` and `(\\.)` with `|` (OR) operator.

Try this:

```
String column = columnname.replaceAll("(\\\")|(\\.)", "");
```